# Thunar crashes when renaming files

Tags: thunar

When I am renaming files one at a time Thunar closes, it doesn't give an error message, it just closes all open instances of Thunar. Then I can open the GUI windows again to rename a few more files before it blinks out again!

When I do a bulk rename by selecting a bunch of files and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> key it does not crash?

It's probably the same as : [Q: Thunar crashes when copying file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603463/thunar-crashes-when-copying-file)
and : [Q: Thunar 1.6.6 Crashing When Moving .docx File](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685197/thunar-1-6-6-crashing-when-moving-docx-file?s=2%7C0.3911)

Found and sent the crash report here: /var/crash/_usr_bin_thunar.1000.crash
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes it crashes when moving a bunch of files, I think I will try to disable Thumblerd - it have caused trouble before!! 
And as Ulrich says we will just have to wait !!  ;-]

Comment: I have the same problem under Ubuntu Studio 15.10. Can we use PCmanFM instead Thunar? ???

Comment: @Juan   Then we misses out of the extended rename options of Thunar, those are what makes it so great!!   I rename a lot of photos and sound-clips, or just move them to a specific (name, event or day) folder, for easy use!

Comment: It seems to be Thumblered, creating thumbnails for pictures- or covers, while we rename or move the files or folders!
It is a global problem, not just Debian - my Suse Gecko thumbleweed XFCE dos the exact same thing!
So how do we tempo rarely  disable Thumblered??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm running XUbuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" and this bug is still present in Thunar version 1.6.10.

I've created a **[PPA](https://launchpad.net/~yuri-sucupira/+archive/ubuntu/thunar1.6.10-fix)** hosting DEB packages that fix this bug for the following *Ubuntu releases (32 bits and 64 bits):

- **Wily Werewolf** (*Ubuntu 15.10)
- **Xenial Xerus** (*Ubuntu 16.04)
- **Yakkety Yak** (*Ubuntu 16.10)

Comment: Great once again Thanks a lot, works dandy on Yakkety Yak ;-)

Comment: Bug has been officially fixed and is available as version 1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 in the official repository. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/1512120

Comment: @adiesner: on my PPA I explain how the user can add such new PPA to his/her system and then cause Thunar to be upgraded to version 1.6.11 available at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.10.1. However, keep in mind that such version **also has a bug** that causes Thunar to freeze under certain (still not too clear) circumstances. I have myself updated to version 1.6.11 but I'm experiencing this problem and have to kill the Thunar process everytime it freezes. My PPA I kept for those who prefer to stick with the patched 1.6.10 version and also for educational reasons.

Comment: I was try to fix this problem with changing source code but it didn't work. Your solution is working. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @kodmanyagha You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://tuxdiary.com/2016/06/10/fix-thunar-crash-move-rename/ also has the following information on this problem and the solution

#### How to confirm the bug

`$ mkdir thunar_test
$ cd thunar_test
$ Thunar .
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do touch "$i.txt"; done
$ while true; do for i in $(seq 1 10); do mv "$i.txt" "$i.txt.txt"; done; sleep 1; for i in $(seq 1 10); do mv "$i.txt.txt" "$i.txt"; done; sleep 1; done`

#### Build with patch or install patched binary

You can follow the instruction and build Thunar by yourself or download prebuilt binary for [Core i5 & i7 CPUs](https://app.box.com/s/dptfgkqlx0w3euxrmkcl9dnwq97g1t6m) there.